# Matters Including Resolution of Olbers' Paradox

Tags: cosmology, electromagnetic-radiation, universe

Is there evidence for galaxies receding from us faster than the speed of light? If so,that might help resolve [Olbers' paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olbers%27_paradox), though other factors must also be taken into consideration. Could such a speed be achieved without acquiring relativistic mass increase? The Cosmic Microwave Background from something 13.8 billion light years away must be further away than any galaxy,yet it is still visible to our instruments.

Comment: [More on Olbers' paradox](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=Olber*+paradox).

Comment: Could such a speed be achieved _even with_ relativistic mass increase?  The way relativistic mass increase is calculated suggests that _any_ speed will cause relativistic mass increase, so it's not clear to me why you would expect _faster than light_ travel to not have similar consequences (or how you expect to have faster than light travel in the first place).

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding here. Cosmic expansion is an expansion of the underlying metric of space, and not a movement in this space, therefore no relativistic mass increase is needed, at high perceived expansion speeds.  
Also Olbers paradox is a historical one, it's resolved. So, good that you think about how to resolve it, but it's not a piece of active research. I also recommend you to study the various https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_horizon s for a more modern view on the topic. CMB: We're reached by CMB photons and always will, because the BB happened everywhere.

Comment: There isn't much question about the superluminal expansion of distant parts of the universe (according to current theories), but there is much confusion about how to interpret it. Reading  this should help you clear it up: https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0310808

Comment: JMac,I don't expect superluminal space travel,as I have made clear in some of my other messages,but of course,you haven't seen them. Far from it,I don't thinks peeds of  even 10% of c will ever be achieved by humans (as opposed to subatomic particles). I was told that galaxies can recede at faster than light speeds,which is why I asked the question.